# The relative virtual path '' is not allowed here

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Any ideas what this problem is? cheers

[image]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to pass [`MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) a page-relative path (`../.....`) instead of a virtual path (`~/.....`).

Comment: in my case I had `~Content/..` instead of `~/Content/..`

Comment: I was trying to load a page like "MyPage.aspx" and get this error. When i change the same call with "~/MyPage.aspx" it worked


_BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/MyPage.aspx", typeof(Page))_

Comment: I am getting the error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\aspnet_merge.exe C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\project_folder-90277028\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir -w project_name -copyattrs C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\project_folder-90277028\obj\Debug\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.dll -a  
aspnet_merge(0,0): Error occurred: An error occurred when merging assemblies: The relative virtual path 'VE/web_form.aspx' is not allowed here.

Comment: @AliShan: [Does it help to clean out your bin folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343229/120955)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I deleted the file 'VE/web_form.aspx' and than moved to solving other errors. once i solve those errors then i come back to this error.

Comment: @AliShan: Sounds like that might be worth creating a separate SO question for.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior separate question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58051236)