# Error 32 An error occurred when merging assemblies

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am getting this error when trying to build in visual studio 2010 what is the purpose for this?

Comment: How are we going to know any more than Google does?  Please add some more detail! Take a look at [An error occurred when merging assemblies](http://dreamlusion.wordpress.com/2008/07/06/an-error-occurred-when-merging-assemblies-access-to-the-path-is-denied/) (the first Google search result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out:

When this error occurs in Visual Studio while building a solution using WDP (Web deployment project):
(Error 32 An error occurred when merging assemblies: The relative virtual path ‘S3.0/global.asax’ is not allowed here. aspnet_merge 1 1 Mems_deploy.), here is what to do:

Check the bin folder in your application and you will find App_global.asax.compiled.
Delete this file
Rebuild your application.
The cause of this error is that the WDP consider that your solution is already build since it found this file in your bin folder.