# Creating database connection using a separate thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Hi I have a static class that has static variables that contain data from the database. I want these variables to be updated every 5 seconds so I created a thread, inside the same class, which will execute a function that will fetch data from the database and update the variables. But I get a `nullReferenceException` pointing to the line where I declare initialize my connection.
Here is my code:

```
public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            isInitialized = true;
            Thread t = new Thread( new ThreadStart(SetProperties));
            t.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void SetProperties()
    {
        //The next line is where the NullReferenceException is pointing to
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("cms.accdb") + "';");

        using (conn)
        { ....
```

Any help, please? Thanks

Comment: There is no `HttpContext.Current` outside of the request thread. Seriously, what you're doing is silly. You need to rethink the design a lot, ASP.NET isn't really the environment for doing something like this.

Comment: @Luaan Hi. Thanks for your reply. But can u please elaborate on "There is no HttpContext.Current outside of the request thread"? And why do you think what I'm doing is silly? please guide me. I'm self-learning ASP.net.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is context-sensitive. It will only have a value on the request thread, and you left that by starting a new thread (that is, your `Initialize` method runs on the request thread, but `SetProperties` doesn't). Which causes your `NullReferenceException`, because you're trying to access properties of a `null` value. Caching is one of the hardest things in computing, so you might want to learn a bit more before attempting anything serious in that regard. Multi-threading is another of the hardest things, and here you're doing both as a beginner. Bad idea :)

Answer (score 1):

In your new thread, you have no access to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` object.
You can replace

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("cms.accdb")
```

With

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("cms.accdb")
```

More info about it here:
[`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @FAngle I got an error 'The relative virtual path 'cms.accdb' is not allowed here.'. any idea?

Comment: @Rian Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455850/the-relative-virtual-path-is-not-allowed-here