# aspnet_merge.exe EROR; The relative virtual path 'VE/web_form.aspx' is not allowed here

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am publishing the asp.net web forms application build in asp.net 4.0

The application builds successfully but after build it gives the following error in the Output window

Generating AssemblyInfo.

Setting [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

Setting [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]

Successfully generated AssemblyInfo file.

Running aspnet_merge.exe.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\aspnet_merge.exe C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\project_folder-90277028\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir -w project_name -copyattrs C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\project_folder-90277028\obj\Debug\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.dll -a aspnet_merge(0,0): Error occurred: An error occurred when merging assemblies: The relative virtual path 'VE/web_form.aspx' is not allowed here.

========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the following files from the project's main folder

```
App_Code.compiled
App_global.asax.compiled
```

and delete the following files from the "bin" folder

```
    App_global.asax.dll
    App_WebReferences.compiled
```

and the error will be solved. I am still looking for the reason behind this problem